# Get closest element by id Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have js code that populate div with some html :

```
 function InvestigationList() {
    var id = $('#idval').text();
    //alert(id);
    var model = {
        id: parseInt(id)
    };
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("ListofInvestigations", "PatientDatabase")',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify(model),
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        processData: false,
        success: function(data) {
            var list = data;
            for (var i = 0; i <= list.length - 1; i++) {
                var investigationList = '<p  style=" color: #1d69b4; font-size: 18px;">'
                    + '<b style=" color: #1d69b4; font-size: 20px;" >Finding from:</b> ' + '<b id="idvalue" style="display:none">' + list[i].id + '</b>'+'<b id="findingval">'+list[i].start +'</b>'+ '</p>'
                    + '<p><b style=" color: #1d69b4; font-size: 20px;">Notice</b></p>'
                    +'<p style=" color: #1d69b4; font-size: 18px;">' +list[i].notice+'</p>';
                $('#panel3').append('<div>' + investigationList + '</div>');
            }
        }
});
}
```

I need to get `findingval` by click on it and `idvalue`

I write this code :

```
 $(document).on('click',
    '#findingval',
    function () {
        var findingval = $(this).text();
        alert(findingval);
        var idvalue = $(this).closest('#idvalue').text();
        alert(idvalue);

    });
```

Finding val is working great, but idavalue isn't getting.

What I doing wrong?

Comment: Um.... There should only be one element for each id. Use classes please.

Comment: Since IDs _have to be unique_ within a document, I doesn't even make sense to search for the "closest" ID - either there is _one single element_ with that ID in the document, or not - "close" has nothing to do with that.

Comment: It's called an ID for a reason.. you don't think every Facebook user would have the same ID. That'd make no sense. ID's are typically unique, so it'd make sense HTML's would be too. Classes define a group of elements, so it's fine using those. "Get the closest element with a certain class" would be a better question and would represent a correctly-developed document.

Comment: Okay. I change it to class. It doesn't work anyway @TyQ.

Comment: _"It doesn't work anyway"_ - the code you have shown so far barely explains what you are trying to do, nor does it allow us to reproduce the problem. So please go read [ask], and how to create a [mcve].

Comment: In code shown closest() won't work because `findingval` and `idvalue` are siblings. Read [closest() docs](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) for better understanding of what it does

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `id` attribute should be unique in the same document so please replace the duplicate ones by the common classes.

When you change all the duplicate ids by common classes you should use these classes on your JS code like :

```
$(document).on('click','.findingval',function () {
  var findingval = $(this).text();
  console.log(findingval);

  var idvalue = $(this).siblings('.idvalue').text();
  console.log(idvalue);
});
```

Demo:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.findingval', function() {
  var findingval = $(this).text();
  console.log(findingval);

  var idvalue = $(this).siblings('.idvalue').text();
  console.log(idvalue);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <p style=" color: #1d69b4; font-size: 18px;">
    <b style=" color: #1d69b4; font-size: 20px;">Finding from:</b>
    <b class="idvalue" style="display:none">idvalue 1</b>
    <b class="findingval">findingval 1</b>
  </p>
  <p style=" color: #1d69b4; font-size: 18px;">
    <b style=" color: #1d69b4; font-size: 20px;">Finding from:</b>
    <b class="idvalue" style="display:none">idvalue 2</b>
    <b class="findingval">findingval 2</b>
  </p>
  <p style=" color: #1d69b4; font-size: 18px;">
    <b style=" color: #1d69b4; font-size: 20px;">Finding from:</b>
    <b class="idvalue" style="display:none">idvalue 3</b>
    <b class="findingval">findingval 3</b>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: they are siblings and missing dot in class selector